# How do I divide Cucumber scenarios if its too long( has many steps )? Any approach or good examples?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

The problem is basically in the header: I have some scenarios with 20-30 steps and Background is not usable. So how do I split those scenarios to several ones with 5-6 steps in one scenario,as cucumber best practice suggests.
Any tips? Someone did this already ? Any examples?

Comment: Have you tried hooks?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I use hooks, but I am in the beginning of my way to optimize scenarios. What you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can look at the subject of the feature and instead of having a file for that you can have a folder.

Lets say you have a feature login, which has now gotten really big

```
features
  |- login.feature
```

```
features
  login
  login.feature
```

Now you can start making files to extract scenarios too

```
features
  login
    | admin_login.feature
    | normal_login.feature
    | 2factor_login.feature
```

It should be fairly clear that you can keep on repeating this pattern.

As far as analysing your scenarios in your existing files. You can

- analyse your scenarios by topic and group them together
- look for things that break a common background, i.e. need a different method in the background or need a new method in the background

Each of these will give you candidates to extract into new files.

You just keep on repeating this until you have clarity in all your feature files.